# When aligned to width LinearLayout layout_weight = “1” requires unit

Tags: xml, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-layout-weight

I use android: layout_weight = "1" to align the elements, but I can't figure out why I need to specify the unit of measurement.

What is the reason for this?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
        <Button
            android:text="+"
            android:layout_width="odp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"// requires a unit
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:id="@+id/bttnPlus"
            android:layout_marginRight="20.0dp" />
        <Button
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_width="odp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"// requires a unit
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginRight="20.0dp"
            android:id="@+id/bttnMinuse" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I can confirm that it will work well with just 1. And this is a good question as I found it strange too, just I have never asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not need a unit and it's an issue of Visua-Studio.

In this [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1149084/on-android-layout-androidlayout-weight1-appears-as.html):

It should be fixed in the Visual-Studio `v16.9 Preview`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem isn't the `layout_weight`. your `layout_width` has typos

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_width="odp"
```

Comment: I changed `android:layout_width="odp"` to this `android:layout_width="0dp"` and the error remained

Comment: Yes, the problem is not about typo.